# How to share data between two components without using higher order functions in React Router and outlet

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I have two components, one called `<Flights/>` and the other called `<FlightResults/>`.

Flights renders a context provider for the rest of the application.

```
const Flights = () => {
  return (
    <FlightSearchContext.Provider
      value={{
        typeOfTrip,
        fromAirport,
        departureDate,
        returnDate,
        toAirport,
        outGoingFlights,
        searchAirports,
        setSearchAirports,
      }}
    >
     <h1>Some UI</h1>     
    </FlightSearchContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default Flights;
```

```
const FlightResults = () => {
  const { toAirport, outGoingFlights } = useContext(FlightSearchContext);

  return (
    <div>Flight results</div>
  )
}

export default FlightResults
```

Right now I'm declaring both routes in my `index.tsx` file like this.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import Flights from "./Components/Flights/Flights";
import FlightResults from "./Components/Flights/FlightResults";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement
);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
          <Route path="/flights" element={<Flights />} index />
          <Route path="/flights/flight-results" element={<FlightResults />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

`FlightResults` is a child route of `Flights` and it needs to access the context data that is declared in the `Flights` component.

Currently everything works fine but `FlightResults` cant access the data in the `Flights` component.

After a lot of searching around i found out that I should wrap my child components in the `index.tsx` file as below.

```
        <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
          <Route path="/flights" element={<Flights />} index>
            <Route path="/flight-results" element={<FlightResults />} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/hotels" element={<Hotel />} />
          <Route path="/taxi" element={<Taxi />} />
        </Route>
```

and whilst this works the `FlightResults` UI doesn't show under `/flights/flightresults`, a possible fix was to render an `Outlet` component on the `Flights` component like below

```
const Flights = () => {
  return (
    <FlightSearchContext.Provider
      value={{
        typeOfTrip,
        fromAirport,
        departureDate,
        returnDate,
        toAirport,
        outGoingFlights,
        searchAirports,
        setSearchAirports,
      }}
    >
     <h1>Some UI</h1>
     <Outlet/>     
    </FlightSearchContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default Flights;
```

and the above does work but now both UIs show up on `/flights/flightresults/` .as in both `Flights` and `FlightResults` show up on the same URL.

How can I make the right component render on the right URL but also still access the context data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue is that you're mixing what you want *exclusively* to be rendered on `"/flights"` with data you want provided to multiple routes.

## Solution

The `FlightSearchContext.Provider` component of the current `Flights` component should refactored to a [Layout  Route](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes) leaving the UI portion in `Flights` to be rendered on its own route.

Example:

```
const FlightsProvider = () => (
  <FlightSearchContext.Provider
    value={{
      typeOfTrip,
      fromAirport,
      departureDate,
      returnDate,
      toAirport,
      outGoingFlights,
      searchAirports,
      setSearchAirports,
    }}
  >
    <Outlet/>     
  </FlightSearchContext.Provider>
);
```

```
<Route path="/flights" element={<FlightsProvider />}>
  <Route
    index                 // <-- "/flights"
    element={<Flights />}
  />
  <Route
    path="flight-results" // <-- "/flights/flight-results"
    element={<FlightResults />}
  />
</Route>
```

If you are *really* wanting to *not* use an `Outlet` component then you can simply lift the `FlightSearchContext.Provider` higher in the ReactTree. In this case the `FlightsProvider` becomes a normal Wrapper component.

Example:

```
const FlightsProvider = ({ children }) => (
  <FlightSearchContext.Provider
    value={{
      typeOfTrip,
      fromAirport,
      departureDate,
      returnDate,
      toAirport,
      outGoingFlights,
      searchAirports,
      setSearchAirports,
    }}
  >
    {children}     
  </FlightSearchContext.Provider>
);
```

```
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <FlightsProvider>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
            <Route path="/flights" >
              <Route index element={<Flights />} />
              <Route path="flight-results" element={<FlightResults />} />
            </Route>
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </FlightsProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: Question though, im kind of a beginner in react so I'm confused. Your wrapper component called  `FlightsProvider` doesn't render any UI so is it also called a component or is there a name for such . because after googling i found out that `In React, a component is a piece of code that represents a part of a user interface` . Pleaase explain

Comment: @AmohPrince React components render returned JSX, but not all JSX has to be something ***visually*** rendered to the screen. Wrapper components are typically "container" components that wrap "visual", or "presentational", components. They often will house some state/logic that is separate from the presentation UI.

Comment: i forgot to tell you im using typescript and I'm now getting this error `Type '{ children: Element; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'`

Comment: @AmohPrince Where exactly are you seeing that error?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you should not declare `FlightSearchContext.Provider` in `Flights`, but instead above both `Flights` and `FlightResults`.

Adapting this example from the [docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useContext#updating-data-passed-via-context), you can declare the context above both `Route`, and if you need to update data in `Flights`, be sure to include `setWhateverData` in the context so you can update it from any children of the context